# OverLay animation in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I'm doing my own `MyLocationOverlay` implementation to bypass extremely slow current position display.

The problem that I've is that I want to make a little `animation` changing the color of the position `marker` and the only way I know to redraw is to call `invalidate` o `MapView`. But that way I also invalidate all the other overlays. Is there an efficient way if only I want to change color and other overlays don't need redraw?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't.

All overlays are drawing to the same object, so to redraw one, it requires clearing everything, and redraw all of them again.

Even if you add another view to the same layout where is `MapView`, changing that view will result in `MapView.invalidate()` being called.

Regards.